# First appearance of the timelike cylinder spacetime

Tags: physics, relativity-theory, weyl

Spacetimes with causality violations go back a bit of a way (at least as far back as Herman Weyl's "Space, Time and Matter" in 1922, followed by the Gödel spacetime in 1949), but one of the simplest example, the timelike cylinder (Minkowski space with the surfaces $t = 0$ and $t = T$ identified) seems to appear fairly late.

The first example I can find of it is Reichenbach's 1957 "The Philosophy of Space and Time", which features the cylinder p. 272. Unfortunately the book isn't big on bibliographical reference so it is hard to determine if this is its first appearance. Does that spacetime appear in any earlier source?

Comment: Reichenbach's original [Zylinder](https://books.google.com/books?id=2xGoBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA320) is actually from [1928](https://books.google.com/books?id=2xGoBgAAQBAJ&pg=PP5).

Comment: got tricked by the American release date, apparently!

Comment: For Weyl, could you give a page number? https://archive.org/details/spacetimematter00weyluoft

Comment: I don't know if you already knew this, but it seems that the Godel spacetime's CTCs were believed to have special philosophical significance specifically because the Godel spacetime contains matter. The argument is expressed in Godel, "A remark about the relationship between relativity theory and idealistic philosophy," 1949.

Comment: The Weyl mention is p. 274. No specific example, just the general possibility of closed timelike curve.

Comment: Interesting. Weyl describes a CTC, then says, "In actual fact the very considerable fluctuations of the [metric] that would be necessary to produce this effect do not occur in the region of world in which we live." This is wrong, and the timelike cylinder is a counterexample. This suggests that experts didn't understand this topic properly in 1922, but did understand it by 1928.

Comment: Weyl's mention was not followed by Gödel. Lanczos in 1924, and independently van Stockum in 1937, discovered the so-called [van Stockum dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Stockum_dust) solution to the Einstein equations (rotating perfect fluid), which had closed timelike curves.

Comment: The closed timelike curves of the van Stockum model were not noticed until Tipler, if I remember correctly